# Remove or set a height to the Navigation Bar in a FreshNavigationContainer

Tags: freshmvvm

I want to remove the navigation bar from the FreshNavigationContainer page in FreshMvvm. But as the name says, it might not be possible to remove the navigation. So if I cannot remove the bar, is there any way to edit its height?

Comment: Are you working on IOS or Android?

Comment: @hugorgor Android

Comment: And is it the Toolbar you want to remove?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
    ..... >
</ContentPage>
```